# Is there an open source, auto-resuming app for Mac to upload videos to YouTube?

Tags: macos, youtube, upload

I've seen a bunch of questions on general apps, but none seem to address the issue of neither auto-resuming nor of the app being open source (and for Mac).

Even command line tools will do the trick for me.

Comment: Why do you need it to be open source? Are you planning to modify it?

Comment: No, but since this app will naturally have access to my login credentials, if it is open source I can trust it not to abuse it in some way. Even if I would use Little Snitch to prevent a closed source app from phoning home, it could still in principle use its allowed access to google for e.g. emailing home...

Comment: Just because it's open source doesn't mean you can trust it